# Different Behavior Between Light and Dark Modes Upon Change in Orientation?

Tags: swiftui, ios15, swiftui-navigationview, swiftui-tabview

I have a setup with tab views within a navigation view. I have been testing for some time with **light mode** showing that all views work properly when switched between portrait and landscape modes. When I switch to **dark mode**, all the tabs work fine upon change in orientation. When changing orientation in any of the three views in the settings tab, control always falls out to the settings tab.

Why should the behavior be different between light and dark modes when changing the orientation? Am I missing something or is this a bug in Apple software?

This is a working example.   Xcode 13.4.1

```
enum Tabs: String {
    case home
    case history
    case settings
}

// App startup: display tab view
struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var selectedTab: Tabs = .home

    var body: some View {

        NavigationView {
            TabView (selection: $selectedTab) {

                EntryView()
                    .tabItem {
                        Label("Home", systemImage: "house.circle.fill")
                    }.tag(Tabs.home)

                HistoryView()
                    .tabItem {
                        Label("History", systemImage: "clock.fill")
                    }.tag(Tabs.history)

                SettingsView()
                    .tabItem {
                        Label("Settings", systemImage: "gear")
                    }.tag(Tabs.settings)
            }
        }.navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
    }
}

struct  EntryView: View {

    var body: some View {

        VStack {
            Text("This is Entry View")
        }
    }
}

struct  HistoryView: View {

    var body: some View {

        VStack {
            Text("This is History View")
        }
    }
}


// display settings menu
struct SettingsView: View {

    var body: some View {

        VStack (alignment: .leading) {

            Form {
                NavigationLink(destination: BaseView()) {Text("View A")}
                NavigationLink(destination: ManCurView()) {Text("View B")}
                NavigationLink(destination: ManCatView()) {Text("View C")}
            }
        }
    }
}

struct BaseView: View {

    var body: some View {

        VStack {
            Text("This is View A")
        }
    }
}


struct ManCurView: View {

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("This is View B")
        }
    }
}


struct ManCatView: View {

    var body: some View {

        VStack {
            Text("This is View C")
        }
    }
}
```

Entry in portrait mode: light mode
https://i.stack.imgur.com/qj0fZ.png

Same view but rotated orientation to landscape: stays in view https://i.stack.imgur.com/U9rhg.png

Entry in portrait: Dark mode
https://i.stack.imgur.com/my9PG.png

Same view but rotated orientation to landscape: exits view and returns to menu
https://i.stack.imgur.com/qPXef.png

Answer (score 0):

I submitted a bug report to Apple: FB10376279